# Java replaceAll with accents

Tags: java, replaceall

So basically I have a string like this:

```
"orom asd örom asddfkdjk öröm lkkllkl Örom oRÖM"
```

I want to search the word "orom" in it, and I need to get back this string:

```
"<font color='#ff0000'>orom</font> asd <font color='#ff0000'>örom</font> asddfkdjk <font color='#ff0000'>öröm</font> lkkllkl <font color='#ff0000'>Örom</font> <font color='#ff0000'>oRÖM</font>"
```

How can I do this with a simple replaceAll and a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = "orom asd örom asddfkdjk öröm lkkllkl Örom oRÖM";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("([oOöÖ][rR][oOöÖ][mM])", "<font color='#ff0000'>$1</font>"));
```

That should work for you and give you the following.

```
<font color='#ff0000'>orom</font> asd <font color='#ff0000'>örom</font> asddfkdjk <font color='#ff0000'>öröm</font> lkkllkl <font color='#ff0000'>Örom</font> <font color='#ff0000'>oRÖM</font>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(O|o|ö|Ö)(r|R)(O|o|ö|Ö)(m|M)
```

Should work for the initial regex, then the following is what you'd replace it with:
    `<font color='#ff0000'>$&</font>`
This is because $& represents the matched text and so it encases the matched text in the tags around the $&.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to find the string would be something like (o|O|ö|Ö)(r|R)(o|O|ö|Ö)(m|M)